# Geckodriver and Selenium with Raspberry Pi using Python gives "connection refused"

Tags: python, linux, selenium, firefox, raspberry-pi

I am trying to open any website using Geckodriver and Selenium for Python. However when Firefox is initiated by Selenium, the URL bar remains empty. After 60 seconds or so I receive an error in the kernel stating: `WebDriverException: Message: connection refused`.

This is the stuff I'm using:

- Linux Raspberry Pi 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP
- Selenium 3.8.0
- Geckodriver 0.19.1
- Python 2.7.9
- Firefox esr 52.5.0 (32-bit)

I have seen other posts about this problem:

- question #18768658
- question #725262

Here is my code:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0.0"

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type",2)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.autoconfig_url", "127.0.0.1:4444")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
browser.get("http://www.google.com")
```

I saw another person mentioning setting the proxy type to auto in the code so I tried that as well. However the problem persists.

Does anybody know a solution for this problem? I am guessing it has something to do with the versions of Geckodriver and Selenium being incompatible? When I look at the geckodriver.log it says this:

```
1513080263669   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.1
1513080263692   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:56782
1513080265346   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.pBJH12y6ylm0"

(firefox-esr:4841): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox-esr:4841): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox-esr:4841): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(firefox-esr:4841): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
1513080266564   addons.manager  DEBUG   Application has been upgraded
1513080266729   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
1513080266740   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
1513080266772   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/GMPProvider.jsm
1513080266794   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/PluginProvider.jsm
1513080266802   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: XPIProvider
1513080266807   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
1513080266812   addons.xpi  INFO    SystemAddonInstallLocation directory is missing
1513080266821   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping e10srollout@mozilla.org to /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1513080266824   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping aushelper@mozilla.org to /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1513080266829   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping firefox@getpocket.com to /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1513080266833   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping webcompat@mozilla.org to /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1513080266840   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
1513080266847   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
1513080266850   addons.xpi  INFO    SystemAddonInstallLocation directory is missing
1513080266855   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loaded add-on state from prefs: {}
1513080266866   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on e10srollout@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1513080266879   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of e10srollout@mozilla.org
1513080266884   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on aushelper@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1513080266890   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of aushelper@mozilla.org
1513080266894   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on firefox@getpocket.com in app-system-defaults
1513080266899   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of firefox@getpocket.com
1513080266903   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on webcompat@mozilla.org in app-system-defaults
1513080266905   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of webcompat@mozilla.org
1513080266911   addons.xpi  DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} in app-global
1513080266918   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1513080266921   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: true, state: {"app-system-defaults":{"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","st":1510791374000},"aushelper@mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi","st":1510791374000},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","st":1510791374000},"webcompat@mozilla.org":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi","st":1510791374000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","st":1510791374000}}}
1513080267007   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Opening XPI database /tmp/rust_mozprofile.pBJH12y6ylm0/extensions.json
1513080267017   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on e10srollout@mozilla.org installed in app-system-defaults
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1513080267120   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267126   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on aushelper@mozilla.org installed in app-system-defaults
1513080267162   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting timer
1513080267180   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267182   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on firefox@getpocket.com installed in app-system-defaults
1513080267254   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267256   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on webcompat@mozilla.org installed in app-system-defaults
1513080267298   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267310   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} installed in app-global
1513080267344   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267350   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering startup change 'installed' for e10srollout@mozilla.org
1513080267423   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1513080267466   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method install on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.10
1513080267480   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-system-defaults:e10srollout@mozilla.org visible
1513080267483   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267485   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering startup change 'installed' for aushelper@mozilla.org
1513080267490   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1513080267511   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method install on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
1513080267512   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-system-defaults:aushelper@mozilla.org visible
1513080267524   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267529   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering startup change 'installed' for firefox@getpocket.com
1513080267539   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1513080267574   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method install on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1513080267575   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-system-defaults:firefox@getpocket.com visible
1513080267578   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267581   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering startup change 'installed' for webcompat@mozilla.org
1513080267588   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1513080267623   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method install on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1513080267624   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-system-defaults:webcompat@mozilla.org visible
1513080267630   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267632   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Make addon app-global:{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} visible
1513080267637   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267642   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"e10srollout@mozilla.org","syncGUID":"{e3980b9f-314d-4e2f-8419-0bdeb4a12245}","location":"app-system-defaults","version":"1.10","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Multi-process staged rollout","description":"Staged rollout of Firefox multi-process feature.","creator":null,"homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","installDate":1510791374000,"updateDate":1510791374000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"skinnable":false,"size":8145,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"52.5.0","maxVersion":"52.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":true,"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false,"mpcOptedOut":false}
1513080267643   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of e10srollout@mozilla.org
1513080267647   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"aushelper@mozilla.org","syncGUID":"{8ebfa06f-79a4-423a-97a5-9222a5b484b2}","location":"app-system-defaults","version":"2.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Application Update Service Helper","description":"Sets value(s) in the update url based on custom checks.","creator":null,"homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi","installDate":1510791374000,"updateDate":1510791374000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"skinnable":false,"size":8488,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"52.5.0","maxVersion":"52.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":true,"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false,"mpcOptedOut":false}
1513080267648   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of aushelper@mozilla.org
1513080267651   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"firefox@getpocket.com","syncGUID":"{a0994009-2a31-438d-aea0-3b2ff771fbec}","location":"app-system-defaults","version":"1.0.5","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Pocket","description":"When you find something you want to view later, put it in Pocket.","creator":null,"homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","installDate":1510791374000,"updateDate":1510791374000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"skinnable":false,"size":920281,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"52.5.0","maxVersion":"52.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":true,"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false,"mpcOptedOut":false}
1513080267652   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of firefox@getpocket.com
1513080267655   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"webcompat@mozilla.org","syncGUID":"{ce323227-e052-4ebe-8823-e261c2b1fc9c}","location":"app-system-defaults","version":"1.0","type":"extension","internalName":null,"updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Web Compat","description":"Urgent post-release fixes for web compatibility.","creator":null,"homepageURL":null},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi","installDate":1510791374000,"updateDate":1510791374000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":true,"skinnable":false,"size":1456,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"52.5.0","maxVersion":"52.*"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":true,"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false,"mpcOptedOut":false}
1513080267656   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of webcompat@mozilla.org
1513080267660   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating XPIState for {"id":"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","syncGUID":"{96795508-367f-4489-814b-aa113c8ffef6}","location":"app-global","version":"52.5.0","type":"theme","internalName":"classic/1.0","updateURL":null,"updateKey":null,"optionsURL":null,"optionsType":null,"aboutURL":null,"icons":{"32":"icon.png","48":"icon.png"},"iconURL":null,"icon64URL":null,"defaultLocale":{"name":"Default","description":"The default theme.","creator":"Mozilla","homepageURL":null,"contributors":["Mozilla Contributors"]},"visible":true,"active":true,"userDisabled":false,"appDisabled":false,"descriptor":"/usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","installDate":1510791374000,"updateDate":1510791374000,"applyBackgroundUpdates":1,"skinnable":true,"size":4932,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":false,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":true,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"52.5.0","maxVersion":"52.5.0"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false}
1513080267662   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
1513080267674   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Save changes
1513080267676   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
1513080267676   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Updating add-on states
1513080267683   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Writing add-ons list
1513080267698   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1513080267702   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 2.0
1513080267710   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1513080267717   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.10
1513080267730   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1513080267739   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1513080267773   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for /usr/lib/firefox-esr/browser/features/webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1513080267777   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1513080267806   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1513080267810   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1513080267811   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1513080267813   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1513080267816   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1513080267823   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1513080267925   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1513080267932   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1513080267933   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1513080267938   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1513080267943   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1513080267950   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1513080272674   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828
1513080272886   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1513080272887   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1513080272890   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1513080273035   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1513080273044   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1513080273062   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1513080273111   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
1513080274463   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
1513080274467   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 19

(/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr:4905): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

(/usr/lib/firefox-esr/firefox-esr:4905): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed
```

Comment: Downgrading to geckodriver v0.18.0 fixed fixed it for me.